# Changing color of any object in the image

Tags: image-processing

I have images of my room and want to see how my room will look with different colors of wall paints. Is there any s/w that I can use? Or is there any standard algorithm which I can use in any language to test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Photoshop or GIMP to try to recolor the walls by hand, (this would be difficult and probably not give you a very accurate representation-- lighting and reflections and such make things complicated) but other than this, no.